# Evento Jquery duplicado em chamada ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, javascript-eventos

Boa tarde pessoal, estou com a seguinte situação:
Tenho minha página chamada **Estoque.html**, nela contém os eventos JQueries pertencentes a ela, por enquanto tudo normal, porém nessa página há um botão chamado **Filtro** que abre um modal e o preenche (com chamada ajax) com conteúdo da página chamada **Estoque_filter.html**, contudo nela há um evento JQuery que chama outro ajax e faz umas alterações internas na sessão.

Bom meu problema é, toda vez que clico no botão Filtro executo normalmente as tarefas, fecho o modal e clico novamente no botão, o evento JQuery que está na página Estoque_filter.htlm é duplicado, triplicado, etc dependendo de quantas vezes clico para carregar o modal, assim fazendo varias vezes a chamada do segundo ajax mencionado a cima.

Segue exemplo:

**Estoque.html**

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button id="filtro">Filtro</button>
        <div id="modal" style="display:none;">

        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#filtro").click(function(){
                OpenModal('Estoque_filter.html');
            }); 
            function OpenModal(url){
                $.ajax({
                    method:"GET",
                    url: url,
                    async: true
                }).done(function (data){
                    $("#modal").html(data);
                    $("#modal").css("display","block");
                });
            }   
        </script>

    </body> 
</html>
```

**Estoque_filter.html**

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button id="altera">Altera Sessão</button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#altera").click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    method:"GET",
                    url: 'altera_sess.php',
                    async: true
                }).done(function (data){
                    $("#modal").css("display","none");
                });
            }); 
        </script>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Depois de clicar não é só desabilitar o botão imediatamente quando clicar nele e o habilitar na resposta do ajax?

Comment: Não, pois esse botão pode ser clicado varias vezes, o problema está na hora que chamo novamente o modal e ele preenche novamente o evento JQuery. Ai ele chama o evento que já existia e o que acabou de ser colocado com o JQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, a chamada ajax do jquery já assíncrona. Não precisa do async: true nesse código.
Segundo, coloque os eventos no DOM Ready do JQuery. com o código abaixo:

```
$(function() {
    $("#altera").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            method:"GET",
            url: 'altera_sess.php'
        }).done(function (data){
            $("#modal").css("display","none");
        });
    });
});
```

O código acima não deve duplicar a chamada de eventos mas provavelmente você não colocou todo o código que usa na sua página. 
Se você ficar chamando o .click do jquery ele vai adicionando a chamada ao listener e irá empilhar um monte de chamadas.
Existe várias formas de limpar e uma forma é usar `$("#altera").unbind();`.
Outro caso pode ser o evento click estar associado a outra tag e o event bubbling do javascript estar disparando ele.
Tente isso que postei ai e comente se funcionou ou não.

Comment: Busquei saber sobre esse unbind(), e lá diz que foi substituído por off(), usei e deu certo, porém meu medo é depois dar memory leak em algum momento onde o javascript salva os eventos, pois pelo que li ele não remove da pilha de eventos ele apenas desassocia do elemento da página. Sabe se é possível causar algum tipo de memory leak fazendo isso?

Answer (score 2):

Use o método [.one()](https://api.jquery.com/one/) no jQuery do aquivo `Estoque_filter.html`. Ele dispara o evento apenas uma vez e depois o remove. Assim não irá empilhar eventos:

```
$("#altera").one("click", function(){
    $.ajax({
        method:"GET",
        url: 'altera_sess.php',
        async: true
    }).done(function (data){
        $("#modal").css("display","none");
    });
});
```

## Bônus

Em vez de usar `$("#modal").css("display","none");`, o jQuery possui um método próprio para esconder elementos. Use `$("#modal").hide();`.

Em vez de usar duas linhas para o mesmo seletor:

```
$("#modal").html(data);
$("#modal").css("display","block");
```

Use:

```
$("#modal").html(data).show();
```

O método `.hide()` esconde e o `.show()` mostra.

Comment: Vlw, irei testar esse método .one(), assim que testar posto se deu certo.

Comment: Deu certo como me indicou também, porém com o one eu não tenho controle de quando desassociar o evento, e com o off() eu desassocio somente quando tenho certeza que não irei mais utilizar. De qualquer forma, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Vc pode usar off() com o one() também. A propósito, esse jQuery dessa página carregada deveria estar na página principal. Assim vc não teria todo esse problema.

Comment: Muito boa a sua contribuição @Sam. Eu nem sabia que existia esse .one().

Comment: É que a página que eu carrego será carregada em outros lugares e o comportamento dos eventos serão os mesmos.